# ActiveRecord Validate Uniqueness with Scope Allowing Nil on Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a validation that looks like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :author
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :author_id }

end
```

The problem is that I want to allow duplicate names where the author id is nil.  Is there a way to do this using the validates method (and not a custom validation)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, with a [`Proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html) and `:unless` on the validator.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :author
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :author_id }, unless: Proc.new { |b| b.author_id.blank? }

end
```

**Recommended Reading:** http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless

Answer (score 11):

Make it conditional:

```
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :author_id }, if: :author_id?
```

Comment: I would say that this one is more pretty, and it should be a preferred solution

Comment: Anyone tried if this works? It did not work for me